# WCF RIA services and System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

Tags: silverlight, ria

I am developing my first project using WCF RIA services. I was able to build a small application and ran it successfuly on localhost. When tried to upload on a server,  I got the following error when browsing it :

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

I looked for this reference on my project and did not find it. I tried to add it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server, but Visual Studio warns me:

> You cant add a reference to
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll as it was not built
>   against the silverlight runtime.silverlight projects will only work
>   with silverlight assemblies

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: on my .Web under references, found the needed dll.On properties, changed copy local to True

Comment: Don't forget to install RIA services on the target servers. There's a SERVER=True property you need to pass to the installer to get it to bypass the check for Visual Studio. An example would be: msiexec.exe /i RiaServices.msi SERVER=True